# Data Binding between a Browser and C# Application

Tags: javascript, c#

Is it possible to send back and forth data between a browser and a C# application?

Example usage case:

Click a button and it will load a page and tell the C# app to go to example.com get the response and send it back to the browser as a variable and then use that variable however.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes it is. This question is too broad however because there are a multitude of methods to do that.

Comment: is it possible? Yes. did I answer the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. There are couple of options to do this.

1. Create a c# http server. The webpage will post all the requests to your c# application and you can handle everything (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.httpserver(v=vs.118).aspx)
2. Register a Uri scheme (http, https are examples of schemes. So register something like stackoverflow://.... ).  eg: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914(v=vs.85).aspx
   Clicking this link will invoke your app. The downside is that you need to make some registry changes.

Naz